How can Save several objects from several session in Cart in ASP.NET
I have a step form for my cart (with One view) , my method in controller is : Checkout
step1: I save Items and ... in session
step2. choose address.
step3. I want save delivery time in new session
I save it in new session but i have 2 problem:
If I save in a method and redirect it to checkout , the cart will be refresh , and form return to the first step
if I return the data of method with ajax, it returns ajax but if I send to method with ajax it will be refresh again. how can I use and save step3 after get Checkout form( when we enter in cart)
this is my method to save:
     [HttpPost]
     public IActionResult SaveDeliveryAndPaymentDetailsInSession(CartViewModel model)
     {
         if (model != null && model.CartDeliveryDateViewModel != null)
         {
             var deliveryAndPaymentDetails = new CartDeliveryAndPaymentDetails
             {
                 DeliveryDate = model.CartDeliveryDateViewModel.DeliveryDate,
                 DeliveryTime = model.CartDeliveryDateViewModel.DeliveryTime,
                 Details = model.CartDeliveryDateViewModel.Details,
                 PaymentMethod = model.CartDeliveryDateViewModel.PaymentMethod
             };

             _orderService.SaveDeliveryAndPaymentDetailsInSession(deliveryAndPaymentDetails);

             var response = new
             {
                 success = true,
                 // Optionally return updated form data
                 formData = model // Assuming model is updated and returned
             };

             return Json(response);
         }
         else
         {
             // Handle the case where model or its properties are null
             return RedirectToAction("CheckOut"); // Or any other appropriate action
         }

     }

and this is my checkout :
   [HttpGet("/UserPanel/CheckOut")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> CheckOut(int? activeTab )
   {


       var text = await _siteService.GetSiteSettingForEdit();
       var tax = text.Tax;

       var userId = User.GetCurrentUserId();

       // Get From Session
       var cartItems = _orderService.GetFromSession();

       // Update ClientId In ShowCart after Login
       foreach (var item in cartItems)
       {
           if (item.ClientId == 0)
           {
               item.ClientId = userId;
           }
       }


       // Get user addresses
       var userAddresses = await _orderService.GetClientContactInfoById(userId);

       // بازیابی جزئیات تحویل و پرداخت از سشن



       var deliveryDetails = _orderService.GetDeliveryAndPaymentDetailsFromSession();


       // we check it in repo and create a list:
       //    List<CartAddressViewModel> cartAddresses = new List<CartAddressViewModel>();
       //so we don't need to check if null, because in repo 100% create a list for it with object, but not null


       // Create CartViewModel
       var cartViewModel = new CartViewModel
       {
           Items = cartItems,
           Tax = tax,
           CartAddresses = userAddresses,
           CartDeliveryDateViewModel = deliveryDetails


       };


       ViewData["ActiveTab"] = activeTab ?? 0;



       await GetStateAndDistricts();

       return View(cartViewModel);
   }


I don't get the point the data returned  from the ajax, it will also refresh. Ajax success method is the javascript codes, if you don't write the redirect inside it, it will not refresh the page. In my opinion, using ajax is the right way.

You can do step3 with Ajax call without refresh page,
something like this:
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#deliveryForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveDeliveryAndPaymentDetailsInSession", "YourControllerName")',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    alert(response.message);
                    // Optionally, you can navigate to the next step or update the UI
                } else {
                    alert(response.message);
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('An error occurred while saving delivery details.');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

and after that, make sure your session save correctly:
public class OrderService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public OrderService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void SaveDeliveryAndPaymentDetailsInSession(CartDeliveryAndPaymentDetails details)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("DeliveryDetails", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(details));
    }

    public CartDeliveryAndPaymentDetails GetDeliveryAndPaymentDetailsFromSession()
    {
        var detailsJson = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("DeliveryDetails");
        return detailsJson != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CartDeliveryAndPaymentDetails>(detailsJson) : new CartDeliveryAndPaymentDetails();
    }
}

and finally, make sure you checkout action retrieve session data correctly:

public async Task<IActionResult> CheckOut(int? activeTab)
{
    // ..... your code ....

    // Retrieve delivery details from session
    var deliveryDetails = _orderService.GetDeliveryAndPaymentDetailsFromSession();

   // ..... your code ....
    return View("ViewName");
}


